# jQuery slideup affects the upper part of the div

Tags: jquery, css, slideup

Whenever I try to `SlideUp()` the div of mine, I notice it actually doesn't only slide up from the bottom to the top, but also a bit from the top slides down towards the bottom part. Now, I don't know if it's supposed to be like that, but it's really disturbing and I wonder if it's possible to remove it? I only want it to slide up from the bottom to the top, leaving the top part of the div unchanged.

[image]

The white space between the darker and lighter purple areas is what's being made while it slides up (this is the best explanation I can give). It's only supposed to slide up towards the darker purple area, and not create a white space below it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".toggleLatestUp").click(function() {
        $(".QuickWrap").slideUp("slow");

    });

});
```

The "lighter purple area" which is supposed to slide up, CSS (in case needed):

```
.QuickWrap {
        background: #F8E7FF;
        float:left;
        width: 100%;
        margin:-18px 0 0 0;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 6px 5px #B9AEBD, inset 0px -6px 5px rgba(185, 174, 189, 0.41);
        min-width: 1349px;
    }
```

Darker purple area, CSS:

```
#HeadOverlay {
    background: #9b59b6;
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-image: url("/templates/images/diagmonds.png");
    min-width: 1349px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="HeadOverlay">
    text
</div>
<br style="clear:both;">
<div class="QuickWrap">
    text
</div>
```

Note: Doesn't matter what I have inside those 2 blocks.

Comment: Can you give your html ? Or make a jsfiddle ?

Comment: @Alteyss I have added the HTML to the OP.

Comment: Ok. I'll be right back ;)

Comment: Can you can check my answer so it can help other people ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it. It was acting so weird because of the negative 18 margin `.QuickWrap` had. When I moved it to `#HeadOverlay` instead, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

This actually works:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGvyqz

```
      if ( $(".QuickWrap:first").is( ":hidden" ) ) {
          $(".QuickWrap").show( "slow" );
      } else {
          $(".QuickWrap").slideUp();
      }
```

Your wrap part is meant to slideUp by showing it when it is not.

And about your white space problem :

Replace your `margin:0px 0 0 0;` by `margin: 0;` in .QuickWrap

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Unfortunately this doesn't solve the problem. It jumps down to the else block and slideUp() just like it did before. I updated the HTML once again, by having a break there you will see what I mean.